# Where were "should", "shall", and "must" in the 18th Century?

Tags: grammar, british-english, orthography, history, modal-verbs

According to the following [Google Ngram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=should%2Cshall%2Cmust%2Cwill&year_start=1650&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=10), in the U.K. the modals *should, shall,* and *must* were virtually missing from English writing during the 18th Century (I've added *will* for a comparison modal which was unaffected).

I have never seen this mentioned anywhere, and I couldn't find it in a brief web search. What happened? Was this a real phenomenon, or could this somehow be an artifact of Google Ngrams? Were these modals absent from speech, or just formal writing? More interestingly, how did they get reintroduced? A brief search shows that Shakespeare definitely used these words quite frequently.

[image: Ngram graph showing usage of "should", "shall", "must" and "will" since 1650]

Comment: What a fascinating question!

Comment: @PeterShor: NGram is a fine tool, but what about a more mechanistic interpretation or the data... It seems to me that there is continuous decline the use of all these words after 1825 which is an absurd. What has replaced their use? What has come up in lieu of "will" or "shall"? Do people use the future tense less and less? (Maybe it suggests a manifestation of massive pessimism... )

Comment: See these two brilliant articles from 2006 that exploit this "feature" of Google Book Search and Google Ngrams: [The Rules for Long S](http://babelstone.blogspot.com/2006/06/rules-for-long-s.html) and [The Long and the Short of the Letter S](http://babelstone.blogspot.com/2006/07/long-and-short-of-letter-s.html).

Comment: @PantelisSopasakis  All modals have been declining, perhaps more markedly in print because of increasing colloquialization. *Will/shall* have been partially supplanted by *be going to* and by contractions with *'ll*, *must* by *have to*, *should/ought to* by *be supposed to*.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

This was a problem with Google's optical character recognition (OCR) mistaking the [long s (ſ)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_s) as an *f*.

However, [Google](http://books.google.com/ngrams/info) has since improved their OCR:

> When we generated the original Ngram Viewer corpora in 2009, our OCR wasn't as good as it is today. This was especially obvious in pre-19th century English, where the elongated medial-s (ſ) was often interpreted as an f, so best was often read as beft. Here's evidence of the improvements we've made since then, using the corpus operator to compare the 2009 and 2012 versions:
>
> [image: Chart showing many pre-1820 beft results in the 2009 corpus, but hardly any in the 2012 corpus]

---

Here's the original chart from the question, with the 2009 corpus:

[image: Strange dips]

Here's a chart with the same words but with the [new 2012 corpus](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=should,shall,must,will&year_start=1650&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=). This is much smoother and no longer has the large dip:

[image: a much smoother chart]

---

Here's the chart from the other answer, with the 2009 corpus:

[image: Strange dips]

And here it is with the [new 2012 corpus](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=should,shall,must,will,fhould,fhall,muft&year_start=1500&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=). This shows hardly any *muft* or *fhall* type words:

[image: hardly any muft type words]

Comment: I’m glad to see that they now recognize ſ U+017F `LATIN SMALL LETTER LONG S` as an alias of the regular round s, although that does mean you can no longer search for it separately. But I’m quite displeased with their [lame scan of Sir Frederick Madden’s translation of Laȝamon’s Brut](http://books.google.com/books?id=DOJRHk2MM9YC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false), as it (next to) never correctly processes any of the thorns, yoghs, or eths.

Comment: See the [conversation in chat beginning here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7107235#7107235) for how they only manage the long-s, and nothing else.

Answer (score 98):

Interesting! I suspected the reason was that the character *s* used to be written somewhat like the present-day *f*. (It would look like *s* only when it was the [last character of a word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_s).) I looked at some of the OCRed documents that Google Ngrams links to. That only strengthened my suspicion.

Look at [this plot](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=should%2Cshall%2Cmust%2Cwill%2Cfhould%2Cfhall%2Cmuft&year_start=1500&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=10) (also below).
I have plotted for "should,shall,must,will,fhould,fhall,muft".

We had some very important literary works between the late 1500s and the early 1600s. I guess these have been re-published with the old-fashioned *s* replaced, and therefore, OCR worked better.

[image: added fhall,fhould,muft, and extended the range]

Comment: It looks like this is right! http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=should%2Cshall%2Cmust%2Cwill%2Cfhould%2Cfhall%2Cmuft&year_start=1650&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=30 shows that the fall of should is accompanied by an equal rise in fhould, etc.

Comment: Yup. I changed the time period in my link now.

Comment: So it was Google Ngrams.

Comment: @Prof. Shor: One important (to me) consequence is that it shows why we can't rely on (just) Google NGrams to settle questions about early Modern English.

Comment: Great answer to a great question. The version of "s" that looks like "f" is called "[long s](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_s)" and Google's OCR definitely doesn't detect them at all. I tried with ſhould,ſhall,muſt and got zero.

Comment: @prash can you include the plot in your answer? that way both images can be compared from this single Q&A.

Comment: @DuckMaestro: I now figured out how it's done!

Comment: @Peter Shor See also this [blog post](http://babelstone.blogspot.com/2006/06/rules-for-long-s.html), which details exactly when the long _s_ and other ligatures disappeared from different languages, including English, using Google's N Grams.

Comment: Very interesting answer. It is also amusing to see the effect in other words as well: http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=fuch%2Csuch%2Cpleased%2Cpleafed&year_start=1500&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=10

Comment: @Billare your comment deserves its own answer, since it definitely shouldn't languish here in the comments!

Comment: @Paul Wagaland: you can have fun with another letter; try http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=tbe%2Cbis%2Cber&year_start=1500&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=10
If you discover more letters, let me know.

Comment: @prash: Google has recently improved their OCR. See my [answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/92166/9001).

Answer (score 8):

Though I know the question has been answered by showing changes in the *Google* OCR, I thought it would be helpful to see actual references to the word ***shall*** as found by human researchers in 18th century writing, instead of relying on the OCR compilation.

Before seeing the answer to this question I started researching instances of ***shall*** as given in the *Oxford English Dictionary Online*. In the samples I cite, I have left out the definitions to which each pertains because there are many long, precise variants, and because the querent did not ask for definitions.

Below are a few samples of the quotations from the 18th century that I found, but this is by no means an exhaustive survey of the entire *OED* entry for ***shall.***  I found these examples under  ***shall*** as a verb. I stopped looking after entry **#8** subsection **b.** because there were far too many. These only reflect usage in the 18th century under the first few sections covering the use of ***shall*** *"followed by an infinitive (without to)."*  These *OED* examples include their date and source exactly as presented, but without the links provided in the *OED.*

> 1744   in Atkyns *Chanc. Cases* (1782) III. 166   The words shall and may in general acts of parliament, or in private constitutions, are to be construed imperatively, they must remove them.
>
> 1781   R. B. Sheridan *Trip to Scarborough* v. ii. (ad fin.),   Well, 'fore George, you shan't say I do things by halves.
>   1719   in T. D'Urfey Wit & Mirth V. 113   Shall you and I Lady, Among the Grass lye down
>
> 1719   in T. D'Urfey *Wit & Mirth* V. 113   Shall you and I Lady, Among the Grass lye down a.
>
> 1780   R. B. Sheridan *School for Scandal* ii. iii. 24   What!..shall I
>   forget..when I was at his years myself.
>
> 1741   S. Richardson *Pamela* III. xvii. 89   A pretty thing, truly!
>   Here, I a poor helpless Girl, raised from Poverty and Distress,..shall
>   put on Lady-Airs to a Gentlewoman born.
>
> 1737   Pope *Epist. of Horace* i. i. 97   And say, to which shall our
>   applause belong, This new Court jargon, or the good old song?
>
> 1756   M. Calderwood *Lett. & Jrnls.* (1884) vi. 166,   I beg to
>   know..who I shall inform him inquired so kindly after him.
>
> 1780   R. B. Sheridan *School for Scandal* iii. i. 32   Let our future
>   contest be, who shall be most obliging.
>
> 1746   P. Francis tr. Horace in P. Francis & W. Dunkin tr. Horace
>   *Epistles* ii. i. 26   No Prince so great, so wise, Hath ever risen, or
>   shall ever rise.
>
> 1781   R. B. Sheridan *Trip to Scarborough* ii. i,   So—carry him off!..
>   We shall have him into a fever by-and-by.
>
> 1781   Johnson in Boswell *Life Johnson* (1904) II. 402   You cannot
>   suppose that we shall rise with a diseased body.
>
> 1779   *Mirror* No. 25,   I..shall let my wife and daughters know, that
>   I will be master of my own house.

Since these are only a small sample of the quotes found in the 18th century writing, the word must have been used much more often than was offered in the *OED* because they usually only quote significant examples. The dates of the samples span the century, and show no drop or change in frequency of use.