# What happened to the word "awesome" between 1760 and 1790?

Tags: etymology

Recently I noticed a strong increase in the usage of the word "awesome" between around 1760 to 1790. Then this word became again absolutely uncommon for a while. See the usage graph below.

[image]

What happened there?

Comment: I don't think that blip in the graph constitutes a "strong increase" of the word.  It could have been anything that made the news: a bad storm, or a quote from a sermon, perhaps.  [This might help](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22awesome%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1700,cd_max:1800&lr=lang_en).

Comment: To find out what it was is the question.

Comment: The problem here is that many people disregard the scale on the vertical axis of these graphs. In your example we are talking in the range of 0.00002% as a ratio that is 0.0000002.(six zeroes!) This probably amounts to a single usage found in a single book surrounded by no occurrences.  And if you look below the graph you will see some date ranges.  Clicking on the range containing your "abnormality" you will find a single occurrence.  Try searching with the two words "awesome,common" and see what that looks like.  Then add "awesome,common,the" and see what that looks like. :-)

Comment: @Jim: you're correct (except that it's three uses, not just one). The link I provided in my first comment points to them.

Comment: @JR, yeah, I did a finer search and found one occurence in 1713 and one in 1714. I tried to edit my comment but hit the "5 minute limit"

Comment: I believe Google has tuned Ngrams so it discounts single occurrences.  But a handful of coincidental occurrences is not so rare an event.

Comment: Don't forget that non-final _S's_ were represented before 1800 by _ſ,_ aka "long S", and that OCR usually reads that as a lowercase _f._ What does the graph for _awefome_ look like?

Comment: @JohnLawler that was my first thought as well, after having read [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/39751/19644), but (to save other readers from looking) the Ngram for *awefome* is totally flat.

Comment: Thanks. I searched to see if anybody had mentioned _awefome_ before commenting.

Comment: Also, don't forget that the publication date is being OCR'd, too - quite often I've seen 'hits' in the 1600s or so that, if I clicked through to the actual work, turned out to be misreadings of '1985' or something.  Google Books - along with nGrams - is an awesome tool for research, but don't trust it implicitly.

Comment: @MT_Head: "Date switches" the other way around are even more common (such as when a hit from an 1985 book that turns out to be a 250th anniversary reprint of some classic work).

Comment: J.R. - I've seen that as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> "*To find out what it was is the question*."

Very well, from the "teach a man to fish" series...

Here's the original Ngram:

[image]

Notice the link at the bottom.  Click on that, and you'll get all the results between those dates.  Problem is, most of those results will be between 1900 and 1926.  But notice how the dates are embedded in the URL:

[image]

Next, all we need to do is change the URL to reflect the dates that we want to examine (in this case, the late 18th century):

[image]

and now we can see what is responsible for the so-called strong increase of the word in the late 1700s.

Remember, this only searches through published works.  There's no way to tell (from this tool) whether or not the word was commonly uttered in pubs, churches, homes, farms, or courthouses – not unless someone transcribed those quotes, so that they were subsequently published in searchable articles or books.

Comment: In addition to changing the URL, there's also a "custom range" thingy on the left to let you change the year range.